# How to write into PostgreSQL hstore using Spark Dataset

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hstore

I'm trying to write a Spark Dataset into an existent postgresql table (can't change the table metadata like column types). One of the columns of this table is of type [HStore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) and it's causing trouble.

I see the following exception when I launch the write (here the original map is empty which when escaped gives an empty string):

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO part_d3da09549b713bbdcd95eb6095f929c8 (.., "my_hstore_column", ..) VALUES (..,'',..) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$ErrorTrackingResultHandler.handleError(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2004)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.flushIfDeadlockRisk(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1187)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendQuery(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1212)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:351)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "my_hstore_column" is of type hstore but expression is of type character varying
```

This is how I'm doing it:

```
def escapePgHstore[A, B](hmap: Map[A, B]) = {
  hmap.map{case(key, value) => s""" "${key}"=>${value} """}.mkString(",")
}
...
val props = new Properties()
props.put("user", "xxxxxxx")
props.put("password", "xxxxxxx")

ds.withColumn("my_hstore_column", escape_pg_hstore_udf($"original_column"))
  .drop("original_column")
  .coalesce(1).write
  .mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append)
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, hashedTablePartName, props)
```

If I don't escape the `original_column` from Map[String, Long] to String using `escapePgHstore` I see the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for map<string,bigint>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:137)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType(JdbcUtils.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:292)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.saveTable(JdbcUtils.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:441)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What's the right way to make spark write a valid hstore data type??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out I have just to let postgres try to guess the appropriate type of my column. By setting `stringtype` to `unspecified` in the connection string as described in the [official documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html).

```
props.put("stringtype", "unspecified")
```

Now it works perfectly !!

Comment: This worked great for me! You saved me a ****load of time and this was the only info I could find on the topic. That said, I did find out one more key piece: The `hstore` column you're writing to has to already exist. If the `SaveMode` that Spark is using is set to "overwrite", Postgres never gets a chance to try and parse the text into the `hstore` column; Spark just tells Postgres that it's a `text` column.

Comment: Just to clarify, `SaveMode.Append` on a pre-created table with a `uuid` column data type is vitally important. If you try to run `SaveMode.Overwrite`, Spark will not create the table with a `uuid` column type (`Spark 2.3.0` will fail with: `DataType uuid is not supported.`)

Comment: Great. This worked for me and saved lot of my time.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pyspark code for writing a dataframe to a Postgres Table that has HSTORE JSON and JSONB columns. So in general for any complicated datatypes that have been created in Postgres which can't be created in Spark Dataframe, you need to specify `stringtype="unspecified"` in the options or in the properties that you are setting to any write dataframe to SQL function.

Below is an example of writing a Spark Dataframe to PostgreSQL table using `write()` function:

```
dataframe.write.format('jdbc').options(driver=driver,user=username,password=password, url=target_database_url,dbtable=table, stringtype="unspecified").mode("append").save()
```