# Cant find uuid in org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes

Tags: uuid

We have a PostgreSQL table which has UUID as one of the column. How do we send UUID field in Spark dataset(using Java) to PostgreSQL DB.
We are not able to find uuid field in org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.

Please advice.

Comment: How did you solve it @Venu

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out, despite these resolved issues ([10186](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10186), [5753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5753)) there is still no supported `uuid` Postgres data type as of Spark 2.3.0.

However, [there's a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979336/1080804) by using Spark's `SaveMode.Append` and setting the [Postgres JDBC property to allow string types to be inferred](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html). In short, it works like:

```scala
    val props = Map(
          JDBCOptions.JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
          "url" -> url,
          "user" -> user,
          "stringtype" -> "unspecified"
        )
          
    yourData.write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .format("jdbc")
        .options(props)
        .option("dbtable", tableName)
        .save()
```

The table should be created with the uuid column already defined with type `uuid`. If you try to have Spark 2.3.0 create this table though, you will again hit a wall:

```scala
    yourData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .format("jdbc")
        .options(props)
        .option("dbtable", tableName)
        .option("createTableColumnTypes", "some_uuid_column_name uuid")
        .save()
```

Result:

> DataType uuid is not supported.(line 1, pos 21)

Comment: The unspecified stringtype saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, there is no UUID datatype in SparkSQL. Treating them as String should work because the connector will convert the String to UUID.

I haven't tried with PostgreSQL, but when I used Cassandra (and Scala) it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But when I send as a string, I am getting an error:                                                         
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "myColumnName" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "cashed_UUID" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: I am getting the same error when trying this solution.

Comment: @Venu how did you solve it; we are also getting same error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "myColumnName" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying`. Please help us with sample code