# Spark SQL - Custom Datatype UUID

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to convert the Column in the Dataset from varchar to UUID using the custom datatype in Spark SQL. But i see the conversion not happening. Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

```
val secdf = sc.parallelize( Array(("85d8b889-c793-4f23-93e9-ea18db640039","Revenue"), ("85d8b889-c793-4f23-93e9-ea18db640038","Income:123213"))).toDF("id", "report")
val metadataBuilder = new MetadataBuilder()
metadataBuilder.putString("database.column.type", "uuid")
metadataBuilder.putLong("jdbc.type", java.sql.Types.OTHER)
val metadata = metadataBuilder.build()
val secReportDF = secdf.withColumn("id", col("id").as("id", metadata))
```

Comment: Are you trying to write your dataframe to a Database with UUID as the  column data type? Sometimes, the connector does that implicitly for you.

Comment: yes @philantrovert i am trying to write to the Database with column UUID using the postgres dialect and i am getting the execption

Comment: you should be looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368906/cant-find-uuid-in-org-apache-spark-sql-types-datatypes and https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/7HGAh-j9ZRA

Comment: Apologies for the Delay in Response. I went through the questions already. I get the similar exceptions for the Postgres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i did the work around as we are not able to cast to UUID in Spark SQL, i have added the property in the Postgres JDBC client as stringtype=unspecified which solved my issue in Inserting UUID through Spark JDBC

Comment: [Here is the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979336/1080804) using Postgres `stringtype` JDBC property